# Convert a string that includes both characters and integers to a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, integer

I know how to convert for instance:

```
'1-2=3^4/5' -> [1, '-', 2, '=', 3, '^', 4, '/', 5]
```

but if let's say I want to convert:

```
'12-34=56^78/90' -> [12, '-', 34, '=', 56, '^', 78, '/', 90]
```

Then I have issues.

I tried several things and it never worked perfectly - it either had an edge case where it was not working or there were issues. For instance, one of the problem I had was that the digits after the 1st one of an int was repeated as new elements.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone can take some time to help me.

Thx in advance!

EDIT: Thx to everyone for your quick answers! However, I am kinda new to programming and hence not familiar w/ the modules or methods used.
Would it be possible to do it using only built-in functions?

Comment: Please share your tries in your post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple pattern that select either some digits or a non-digit, will do it

```
pat = re.compile(r"\d+|\D")

parts = pat.findall("1-2=3^4/5")
print(parts)  # ['1', '-', '2', '=', '3', '^', '4', '/', '5']

parts = pat.findall("12-34=56^78/90")
print(parts)  # ['12', '-', '34', '=', '56', '^', '78', '/', '90']
```

Comment: @juicy Note that my solution is 3 times faster than the one you accepted, and even 4 times faster in you compile the pattern one before. Combined with the so much lighter code, I let you decide which one is the real best answer ;)

Comment: @azro you're right, it's just that I am kinda new to programming and hence was not familiar w/ what you did, but I had a look and just changed the 'solution' to the post. Thx again!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group by consecutive digits (using str.isdigit)

```
from itertools import groupby

s = '12-34=56^78/90'

res = ["".join(group) for k, group in groupby(s, key=str.isdigit)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['12', '-', '34', '=', '56', '^', '78', '/', '90']
```

Comment: Thx it worked! Would it be possible to do it using only built-in functions?

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers are way, way better.  But if you feel compelled to do it without any imports, here is a solution.

```
s = '12-34=56^78/90'

output = []
section = []
for e in s:
    try:
        e = int(e)
        section.append(e)
    except ValueError:
            output.append(''.join(map(str,section)))
            output.append(e)
            section = []
            
output.append(''.join(map(str,section)))
```

Comment: @juicy use this answer.